# Reload a model itself during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec, database-cleaner

I use mongoid and I have an ContactField model and an Contact model. In my Contact model, I do:

```
Admin::ContactField.all.each do |field|
field field.field_name.to_sym#, type: ...
end
```

So in prod, dev, that's functionnal, but when I am writing tests, It does not work because the model was load with 0 Admin::ContactField and it won't be reload.

So I am looking for a solution, I didn't find a solution to use reload! like in the console, so I tried that:

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[admin_contact_fields]}
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:truncation)
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    generate_admin_contact_fields
    load '/Users/work/Work/work/app/models/contact.rb'
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

That's seems work, but it doesn't reload, it loads twice. 
So I got lot of warning like

```
WARN -- : Overwriting existing field content_seen in class Contact.
WARN -- : Overwriting existing field content_sent in class Contact.

WARN -- : Overwriting existing field url_c4c in class Contact.
WARN -- : Creating scope :is_valid_contact. Overwriting existing method Contact.is_valid_contact.
WARN -- : Creating scope :email_exists. Overwriting existing method Contact.email_exists.
```

Do you know a better solution? Something pretty good like `reload!` ?
Thanks

Comment: why exactly are you trying to reload the files during the tests?

Comment: @maxpleaner because Contact.rb was loaded before, in my `before` I created ContactFields so Contact hasn't the contacts fields because it was load before. I need to reload it.